# Converting user-specified number of time unit to another time unit, (seconds to weeks, weeks to hours, etc...)

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

Newbie to Java here. I have written a time conversion program that accepts any number from 0 to 9e+18 as valid input ans asks for conversion parameters from the user, eg, from weeks to seconds. Wrote all the calculations in a huge block of if-else-if-else lines inside a do-while loop. Program exits whenever user enters 'q' for quit. My current program works its conversion flawlessly between different time units.

My question is, how do I utilize switch statements in lieu of this horrible block of if-else?

```
if (fromUnit.equals("w") && toUnit.equals("s")) {
        results = userNumber * SECONDS_PER_WEEK;
    System.out.printf("There are %,.2f seconds", results); 
    System.out.printf(" in %,d %s.\n", userNumber, userNumber == 1 ?          "week" : "weeks");
        } else if (fromUnit.equals("h") && toUnit.equals("s")) {
    results = userNumber * SECONDS_PER_HOUR;
            System.out.printf("There are %,.2f seconds", results);
            System.out.printf(" in %,d %s.\n", userNumber, userNumber == 1 ? "hour" : "hours");
    } else if (fromUnit.equals("d") && toUnit.equals("s")) {
            results = userNumber * SECONDS_PER_DAY;
            System.out.printf("There are %,.2f seconds", results);
            System.out.printf(" in %,d %s.\n", userNumber, userNumber == 1 ? "day" : "days");
    } else if (fromUnit.equals("m") && toUnit.equals("s")) {
            results = userNumber * SECONDS_PER_MINUTE;
            System.out.printf("There are %,.2f seconds", results);
            System.out.printf(" in %,d %s.\n", userNumber, userNumber == 1 ? "minute" : "minutes");
    } else if (fromUnit.equals("s") && toUnit.equals("s")) {
            results = userNumber * SECONDS_PER_SECOND;
            System.out.printf("There are %,.2f seconds per second.\n", results);
    } else if (fromUnit.equals("w") && toUnit.equals("m")) {
            results = userNumber * MINUTES_PER_WEEK;
            System.out.printf("\nThere are %,.2f minutes", results);
            System.out.printf(" in %,d %s.\n", userNumber, userNumber == 1 ? "week" : "weeks");
    } else if (fromUnit.equals("d") && toUnit.equals("m")) {
            results = userNumber * MINUTES_PER_DAY;
            System.out.printf("\nThere are %,.2f minutes", results);
            System.out.printf(" in %,d %s.\n", userNumber, userNumber == 1 ? "day" : "days");
    } else if (fromUnit.equals("h") && toUnit.equals("m")) {
            results = userNumber * MINUTES_PER_HOUR;
            System.out.printf("\nThere are %,.2f minutes", results);
            System.out.printf(" in %,d %s.\n", userNumber, userNumber == 1 ? "hour" : "hours");
    } else if (fromUnit.equals("m") && toUnit.equals("m")) {
            results = userNumber * MINUTES_PER_MINUTE;
    System.out.printf("\nThere are %,.2f minutes", results);
            System.out.printf(" in %,d %s.\n", userNumber, userNumber == 1 ? "minute" : "minutes");
        } else if (fromUnit.equals("h") && toUnit.equals("h")) {
            results = userNumber * HOURS_PER_HOUR;
    System.out.printf("\nThere are %,.2f hours in %,d hours.\n", results, userNumber);
    } else if (fromUnit.equals("d") && toUnit.equals("h")) {
            results = userNumber * HOURS_PER_DAY;
    System.out.printf("\nThere are %,.2f hours in %,d days.\n", results, userNumber);
    } else if (fromUnit.equals("w") && toUnit.equals("h")) {
            results = userNumber * HOURS_PER_WEEK;
    System.out.printf("\nThere are %,.2f hours in %,d weeks.\n", results, userNumber);
    } else if (fromUnit.equals("d") && toUnit.equals("d")) {
            results= userNumber * DAYS_PER_DAY;
    System.out.printf("\nThere are %,.2f days in %,d days.\n", results, userNumber);
    } else if (fromUnit.equals("w") && toUnit.equals("d")) {
            results = userNumber * DAYS_PER_WEEK;
    System.out.printf("\nThere are %,.2f days in %,d weeks.\n", results, userNumber);
    } else if (fromUnit.equals("s") && toUnit.equals("ms")) {
            results = userNumber * MICROSECONDS_PER_SECOND;
            System.out.printf("\nThere are %,.3f microseconds in %,d seconds.\n", results, userNumber);
    } else if (fromUnit.equals("d") && toUnit.equals("w")) {
            results = userNumber * WEEKS_PER_DAY;
            System.out.printf("\nThere are %,.3f weeks in %,d days.\n", results, userNumber);
        } else if (fromUnit.equals("h") && toUnit.equals("d")) {
            results = userNumber * DAYS_PER_HOUR;
            System.out.printf("\nThere are %,.3f days in %,d hours.\n", results, userNumber);
    } else if (fromUnit.equals("s") && toUnit.equals("h")) {
            results = userNumber * HOURS_PER_MINUTE * MINUTES_PER_SECOND;
            System.out.printf("\nThere are %,.3f hours in %,d seconds.\n", results, userNumber);                
    } else if (fromUnit.equals("ms") && toUnit.equals("s")) {
            results = userNumber * SECONDS_PER_MICROSECOND;
            System.out.printf("\nThere are %,.3f seconds in %,d microseconds.\n", results, userNumber);
    } else if (fromUnit.equals("m") && toUnit.equals("ms")) {
    results = userNumber * MICROSECONDS_PER_MINUTE;
    System.out.printf("\nThere are %,.3f microseconds in %,d minutes.\n", results, userNumber);
        } else if (fromUnit.equals("h") && toUnit.equals("ms")) {
            results = userNumber * MICROSECONDS_PER_HOUR;
            System.out.printf("\nThere are %,.3f microseconds in %,d hours.\n", results, userNumber); 
        } else if (fromUnit.equals("d") && toUnit.equals("ms")) {
            results = userNumber * MICROSECONDS_PER_DAY;
            System.out.printf("\nThere are %,.3f microseconds in %,d days.\n", results, userNumber);
        } else if (fromUnit.equals("w") && toUnit.equals("ms")) {
            results = userNumber * MICROSECONDS_PER_WEEK;
            System.out.printf("\nThere are %,.3f microseconds in %,d weeks.\n", results, userNumber);
        } else {
            System.out.println("\nCannot calculate!\n");
    }

} while (userNumber >= 0);
}
```

}

Comment: Did you take a look at the `switch` structure ? What do you not understand ?

Comment: I understand the switch syntax. How do I write a switch structure to convert weeks to seconds, weeks to hours, hours to minutes, etc? Am I right to think that each conversion from each time unit would require its own switch statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to use a switch statement is this:

```
String fromTo = fromUnit + toUnit;

switch (fromTo) {
    case "ws": // weeks to seconds
         // ...
         break;
    case "hs": // hours to seconds
         // ...
         break;
    case "ds": // days to seconds
         // ...
         break;
    // ...
}
```

Another way is to put the data into a `HashMap<String, Integer>`

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("ws", SECONDS_PER_WEEK);
map.put("hs", SECONDS_PER_HOUR);
map.put("ds", SECONDS_PER_DAY);
// ...

String fromTo = fromUnit + toUnit;
results = userNumber * map.get(fromTo);
System.out.printf("There are %,.2f to units", results);
System.out.printf(" in %,d %s.\n", userNumber, userNumber == 1 ?          "from unit" : "from units");
```

Comment: This would require the user to enter "ws" when prompted for parameters of conversion. Currently have 3 separate questions for the user: first the type of unit to convert from, then the unit to convert to and last, the value/number.

Comment: @mchlvncntry No this does not require that. See the very first line of the first code snippet? That line concatenates the `fromUnit` and the `toUnit` (which are from two separate questions for the user) into one string.

Comment: I'd love to use HashMap but since this is a beginner class to Java, and we've only gone as far as switch statements, I'd like to be within the bounds of the lecture for now.